# How to select specifc entries in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm dealing with this problem. There is table`orders`(`oid`,`datetime`,`quantity`,`title`,`username`,`mid`).

The table `orders` is updated from php code as far as the features `oid`,`datetime`,`quantity`,`title`,`username` are concerned. The problem is that I want to classify each entry based on both datetime and username so as to gather these entries under an order code in order to make an ordering entry. (I can't think of anything else at the moment).
The question is how can I select those entries that are corresponding to the same username and the same date time.

For example the if I  have 3entries (freddo espresso,latte,freddoccino) belong to the same order procedure (are posted by the same username, tha exact same datetime) and I need to present them to my user as a completed order.

Here is the structure of table `orders`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
`oid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`quantity` INT NOT NULL,
`sum` FLOAT(4,2) NOT NULL,
`title` VARCHAR(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`username` VARCHAR(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`mid` VARCHAR(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`oid`),
KEY `username`(`username`,`mid`,`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=10000;
```

The feature title is foreign key from table `products`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products`(
`title` VARCHAR(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 

`descr` TEXT(255),
`price` FLOAT(4,2) NOT NULL,
`popularity` INT NOT NULL,
`cname` VARCHAR(20)  COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
`mid` VARCHAR(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY(`title`),
KEY `cname` (`cname`, `mid`)
)ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=10000;
```

Sorry If I'm a little uncomprehensive, though I really need some help to come to a conclusion. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: assuming its the same order by date time is dangerous, could easily span over  a second. you should add an order id.

Comment: Can you post you exact table structure?

Comment: You really should assign a common unique `oid` to the same order and put the order items in a separate table using the `oid` as a common key. However if you cannot do that you could at least make sure that the datetime is the same by passing a formatted date in your INSERT query. That way you'll know for sure that a datetime+username combination is unique.

Comment: I'll try to make this thing with unique `oid` now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what the `datetime` value and the `username` values are then you can simply use:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE username = '$username' AND datetime = '$datetime'
```

However, what you would be better off doing is splitting this into two separate tables; something like:

```
Orders
    OrderID
    OrderTime
    UserName

Items
    ItemID
    OrderID
    Title
```

Then you would search in the following way:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.UserName, Items.Title
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Items ON Orders.OrderID = Items.OrderID
WHERE
    Orders.UserName = '$username'
  AND
    Orders.OrderDate = '$datetime'
```

When adding orders you add a record to `Orders` first, and then use that `OrderID` and add it to each item inserted in `Items`...

### Insert Example

```
$mysqli;   //Assuming your connection to the database...
$items;    //Assuming an array of items for the order like: array('Coffee', 'Tea')
$username; //Assuming the user name to be inserted for the order

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Orders(`OrderTime`, `UserName`) VALUES(NOW(), '$username')");
$orderid = $mysqli->insert_id;
foreach($items as $item){
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Items (`OrderID`, `Title`) VALUES($orderid, '$title')");
}
```

**NOTE:** You should make sure to sanitize data before inserting to database...

---

### Storing JSON

Storing `JSON` in a database is going to require you to make sure that you use a field data type that is an appropriate length (e.g. a `blob`).

You mentioned that you retrieve the `titles` as an array from a form so I'm now going to refer to that as `$titles`.

#### Saving to database

```
$username      = '...';                // Username or id to store in database with order
$titles        = array(.....);         // Array of titles from form
$encodedTitles = json_encode($titles); // Convert to JSON

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table_name (titles_field, username_field, date_field) VALUES ('$titles', '$username', NOW())"); // Save to database (assuming already open connection
```

#### Retrieve from database

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT titles FROM table_name WHERE username = 'username_value' AND date_field = 'date_value'"); //Run query to get row
$row    = $result->fetch_assoc();      // Fetch row
$titles = json_decode($row['titles']); // This is the same as the `titles` array from the from above!
```

Comment: Very helpful answer for my thoughts!

Comment: in my php files I've declared products  as array from where I get `title` via checkboxes and quantity via textboxes. Since I have to store array and mysql does not support this in  tables, can I work with procedures for instance or am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to store an `array`? Also, are we talking about your original code? or have you changed it?

Comment: my original code.I had in mind that each oid should be connected with an array of titles chosen while an ordering procedure (multiple entries)

Comment: That's _effectively_ what would happen if you were to change it to what I showed above... With your original code you could store an array in the database as a `json` string and decode it in php when you access it (`json_encode` and `json_decode`). I wouldn't advise that though! I do strongly suggest that you change the database structure though - if at all possible?

Comment: Let me know how you get on! :)

Comment: I'm trying to complete my project and I've decided to follow the lead of json_encode and json_decode. I've searched for some good tutorials, yet found nothing satisfactory for my needs. Is there any chance to explain these to me or some tutorials I can study on? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay, I **do not** recommend this, but it's your project so we'll play by your rules. I'll just update the answer a bit... Out of interest, why have you decided to take this route as opposed to normalising your database?

Comment: I've updated it now with the procedure you would use to store and retrieve `json` from the database. It's fairly straight forward, but if you have any problems/questions feel free to ask

Comment: Because I don't have plenty of time and this part is the 1/5 of my project whereas the else 4/5 are done based on my current database. That's why I'm trying to do it ths way unfortunately. Thanks a lot again for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT quantity,title
FROM orders
WHERE username = ? and datetime = ?
```

Would return the quantity of items for a specific user on specific date. Instead of a date you could use an order id, which might be a bit safer. If you use order id, then username becomes irrelevant as well, since order ids should be unique.

Comment: `oid` is my order id, I put it auto increment. But even though these 3 entries above belong to the same order, they acquire different oid values in my mysql table.That's why I thought of that I described in this topic. How can I deal with it?

Comment: Oh. Sounds like a structural problem. You might want to have a table orders and a table items. Then, your order id would be unique and you could add as many items to a single order id as you like. Is it possible to change your structure or is it too late for that?

Comment: It is possible to make some change, as lon as I can handle it!

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted with the query will help you but you should also consider changing your table structure. Looks like you could have a table named orders and another one named orders_items. Then you could list all the itens from orders_itens matching a single order.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind too during the changes in my database. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will return kind of data where you have the same `unique_id` string for records where `username` and `datetime` are the same.

```
SELECT MD5(a.unique_id), b.* FROM (
    SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(oid) unique_id, `datetime`, username 
        FROM `orders` GROUP BY username, `datetime`

) a
RIGHT JOIN `orders` b 
ON a.`datetime` = b.`datetime` AND a.username = b.username
ORDER BY unique_id, oid;
```

I also have another answer for about 3 thousands characters long but I think this variant will help you more than my long tutorial how to split the table to two tables and how to migrate data into it + php code samples. So I decided not publicate it. )))

**Edit: I think you even can run this one query which is easiest and works faster:**

```
SELECT *, MD5( CONCAT( `username` , `datetime` ) ) unique_id
FROM `orders`
ORDER BY unique_id, oid;
```